# Mapping function for RBF

Tags: math, machine-learning, proof

I am reading about the feature map of the gaussian kernel and I was wondering about the feature map derivation. For the 1-D scalar case, there is a clear explanation:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/kuleuven_svm.pdf
(slide 11)

but how would it work for the 2-D case? During the expansion in the initial case, there will be a dot product. Even after the taylor expansion I don't see why we can just separate them into two feature mappings.